# Twitter search within an iOS app

Tags: ios, twitter, social-networking

After learning how to use Twitter within an iPhone app (with TWTweetComposeViewController), I would like to go one step further.
When the "Tweet Search button" (in my app) is tapped, I would like a view showing up with the result of a given search (for example "water falls") within Twitter.

Is this possible? And if Yes, how?

Since it is possible to fire up Twitter (within an iOS app) and the search is also possible for someone using Twitter manually, I would think the answer to my first question is Yes.
But at this point I have no idea concerning the answer to the second question.

Thanks for any relevant piece of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TWTweet class has a property called completionHandler which returns if successful/fail.

i would use a uiWebview object that will display the main twitter site with a query that will search for example water falls.

Answer (score 0):

See this 
iPhone SDK: First Steps With JSON Data Using the Twitter API
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-json-twitter-api/